# Python: concatenate string and int in a loop

Tags: python, string, string-concatenation

I have a list of integers and I want to concatenate them in a loop.

This is what I have so far

```
a = [3, 4, 6]

temp = []
for i in a:
    query = 'Case:' + str(i)
    temp.append(query)

print(' OR '.join(temp))

>>> Case:3 OR Case:4 OR Case:6
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: A bit shorter: `' OR '.join('Case:' + str(i) for i in a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use generator expression and `str.join` ,

```
' OR '.join('Case: {}'.format(i) for i in a)
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> a = [3, 4, 6]
>>> ' OR '.join('Case: {}'.format(i) for i in a)
'Case: 3 OR Case: 4 OR Case: 6'
```

Comment: yea , though only a slight difference :) .

Comment: Ditto -- beat me to it by a minute!

Comment: Anyway.. enjoy.. I deleted my answer. the net result is the same.. :)

Comment: Thanks everyone who answered! This is great! This is what I am looking for. I just didn't realised it's called generator expression.

Comment: I thought I'd make an answer just because I love comprehensions :p

Answer (score 2):

You can also use map and lambda expressions:

```
temp = map(lambda x: 'Case: '+str(x), a)
```

Comment: This returns a list not a string. You can convert it to the required output by chaining it to a `join` like this: `' '.join(map(lambda i: 'Case:' + str(i) + ' OR', a))`

Comment: I took his code from above and split the converting and joining in two parts like in his code. That is only the line für converting (translation of his for loop).#

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a comprehension:

```
>>> a = [3, 4, 6]
>>> ' OR '.join([ "Case " + str(x) for x in a ])
'Case 3 OR Case 4 OR Case 6'
```

Answer (score 0):

Completing the idea from @Joshua K for using map and lambda (although I think the list comprehension is a better solution):

```
>>> a = [3, 4, 6]
>>> 'OR '.join(map(lambda i: 'Case:' + str(i) + ' ', a))
Case:3 OR Case:4 OR Case:6
```